# What prepositions or expressions are used to say holding hands in German?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, expression

Reading the book "Tambora und das Jahr ohne Sommer(German Edition) Seite 654.

"John Bull, steht mit zwei Kindern an den Händen im Vordergrund des Bildes"

Placed this sentence in Google translate and worked out "an den Händen" means holding hands.

So is the preposition "an" the usual way to say holding hands?

Are there any other prepositions or expressions to say holding hands in German?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sie halten einander an den Händen.

That's a description of what is visible. Use it when no affection is involved.

> Sie halten einander die Hände.

That's a description of their affection for each other which is expressed by them holding hands.

> Sie halten Händchen.

That's a fixed phrase used for the affection a young couple shows in public by holding hands. Use it only for young couples.